# GWT - How to prevent certain functions from appearing in the JavaScript for certain users?

Tags: gwt

I'm conditionally building widgets for the GUI screen depending on the access level of the user. Even though the SuperUser widgets are not created and added to the panel for normal users, I can still find the presence of SuperUser widgets and (worse yet) the SuperUser functions inside the page's JavaScript. I've tried using code splitting (GWT.runAsync) but all that does is delay when the SuperUser functions are visible, it doesn't prevent them altogether.

```
if ("a".equals(userName)) {
  // Create SuperUser widget that calls SuperUser function and add it to the layout panel.
} else {
 // Create User widget that calls User function and add it to the layout panel.
}
```

The above creates **both** widgets and generates **both** functions in the JavaScript. I understand that GWT can compile in obfuscated mode, but we know that's only a "best effort" solution. Is there any way to get GWT to NOT include certain JavaScript functions unless explicitly told to include them? Ideally the SuperUser functions would only exist in the JavaScript if there's actually an execution branch that can access them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Code Splitting](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html) mechanism:

> To split your code, simply insert calls to the method GWT.runAsync at the places where you want the program to be able to pause for downloading more code. These locations are called *split points*.

In your case:

```
if("a".equals(userName))
    GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // this code will be compiled to a separate file
            // and downloaded when GWT.runAsync is executed

            // Create SuperUser widget that calls SuperUser function and add it to the layout panel.
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable reason) {
            Window.alert("Code download failed");
        }
    });
else
    GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // this code will be compiled to a separate file
            // and downloaded when GWT.runAsync is executed

            // Create User widget that calls User function and add it to the layout panel.
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable reason) {
            Window.alert("Code download failed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Code splitting will still make it easy for the user to download the JS - the files are predictably named, if they care at all about finding it, they will.

Answer (score 0):

If you are conditionally checking the user status at runtime in the browser, then the best you could do is to dynamically download a separate javascript library for the appropriate widget from the server and execute it.  But this is pointless unless the javascript is protected on the server side based on server side authentication of the user.

Also, the GWT compiler compiles for applications, I don't think you can build a javascript library.  (Though I could be wrong)